# Meteor user accounts issue - Duplicate account being created with OAuth service (accounts-google)

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working with Meteor User accounts to create users. I have implemented two ways of creating users.

1. By using **accounts-password** to create (default one ).
2. OAuth Services (**accounts-google** and **accounts-facebook**)

A user account generated with **accounts-password** have the document shown below

```
{
  "_id": "DQnDpEag2kPevSdJY",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-10T22:34:17.610Z",
  "services": {
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "XXX"
    },
    "resume": {
      "loginTokens": [
        {
          "when": "2015-12-10T22:34:17.615Z",
          "hashedToken": "XXX"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
 -----
----
}
```

Where as a user account generated with **accounts-google or account-facebook** have the document shown below.

```
{
  "_id": "Ap85ac4r6Xe3paeAh",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-10T22:29:46.854Z",
  "services": {
    "facebook": {
      "accessToken": "XXX",
      "expiresAt": 1454970581716,
      "id": "XXX",
      "email": "myname@gmail.com",
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "first_name": "Ada",
      "last_name": "Lovelace",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXX/",
      "gender": "female",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      }
    },
---
---
---
```

Now the real issue is, Although the email address used is same for both accounts-password and accounts-google (in my case email is myname@gmail.com), two different user accounts are being created.

I am looking for solution Something like below. (Note: Services has both "Password" and "Facebook" sections under single account)

```
{
  "_id": "DQnDpEag2kPevSdJY",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-10T22:34:17.610Z",
  "services": {
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "XXX"
    },
    "facebook": {
      "accessToken": "XXX",
      "expiresAt": 1454970581716,
      "id": "XXX",
      "email": "myname@gmail.com",
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "first_name": "Ada",
      "last_name": "Lovelace",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXX/",
      "gender": "female",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      }
    },
  },
 -----
----
}
```

Is there a way where only one account is being generated in both cases, means if a user is already existed and the same is trying with OAuth service, first account should be used to accommodate the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the above issue with a hack.

In **`imports/startup/server/accounts.js`** I have added the below validation logic which always validates the newly created account.

The idea is, this process checks if user is already existed in database. If the user exists, further checks if its created from `accounts-password` or `accounts-google/facebook` .

Based on the existing type modify the existing fields with new fields and throw an error with a fancy message (This actually prevents the new account to be created).

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {

// first check what is the newly creating service
  var service =
    user.services.google || user.services.facebook || user.services.password;


  if (!service) return true;

  var existingUser = null;
// due to some issues both `Meteor.users.findOne(email)` as well `Account.findUserByEmail(email)` methods have been used to find the existing user status

  if (user.services.password) {
    var email = user.emails[0].address;
    existingUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
      $or: [
        { "registered_emails[0].address": email },
        { "services.google.email": email },
        { "services.facebook.email": email },
      ],
    });

  } else {
    var email = service.email;
    //console.log(" retrieved email ", email);
    existingUser = Accounts.findUserByEmail(email);
  }

  //console.log(" existingUser  : ", existingUser);
  if (!existingUser) return true;

  if (user.services.google) {
    Meteor.users.update(
      { _id: existingUser._id },
      {
        $set: {
          profile: user.profile,
          "services.google": user.services.google,
        },

      }
    );
  } else if (user.services.facebook) {
    Meteor.users.update(
      { _id: existingUser._id },
      {
        $set: {
          profile: user.profile,
          "services.facebook": user.services.facebook,
        },

      }
    );
  } else {
    Meteor.users.update(
      { _id: existingUser._id },
      {
        $set: {
          profile: user.profile,
          "services.password": user.services.password,
          "services.email": user.services.email,
          emails: user.emails,
        },

      }
    );
  }

  throw new Meteor.Error(
    205,
    "Merged with your existing Social Login accounts now. Try refresh the page and sign in again. That should work !!"
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[link-accounts](https://atmospherejs.com/bozhao/link-accounts) package is the recommended way to allow users to add additional services to their account.

Comment: Thanks @storyteller. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Accounts.setPassword`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-setPassword) **on the server** in order to generate a proper bcrypt hash for the accounts:

```js
Accounts.setPassword('Ap85ac4r6Xe3paeAh', 'the-new-password')
```

which will result in

```
{
  "_id": "Ap85ac4r6Xe3paeAh",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-10T22:29:46.854Z",
  "services": {
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "$2b$10$nzHCivxVqxbuFBBPWewPPu.r5x7OR5gJB8PIklU4OoU.WK0MT8jt2"
    },
    "facebook": {
      "accessToken": "XXX",
      "expiresAt": 1454970581716,
      "id": "XXX",
      "email": "myname@gmail.com",
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "first_name": "Ada",
      "last_name": "Lovelace",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XXX/",
      "gender": "female",
      "locale": "en_US",
      "age_range": {
        "min": 21
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt, thanks for the answer. But I am actually facing the duplicate account being created issue. Do you have any suggestion where how to avoid facing that issue ?

Comment: Accounts.setPassword does mit throw such error. Can you please check that you not accidently still call `Accounts.createUser`?